# How to call another asp.net page on button click in asp.net mvc4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to mvc 4.How to call another cstml page on button click in asp.net mvc4

can i use jquery and or c#

Comment: Your question does not have enough information to answer, what are you trying to achieve, what have you tried, show us that you have already put some effort into it and elaborate your problem.

Comment: that is i want to know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to go to another page when a button is clicked?

First stop thinking in "pages" and start thinking in "actions". You cannot call or navigate to another page in ASP.NET MVC: you can call or navigate to another controller action.
If you have a button:

```
<button id="myButton">Click me</button>
```

Can use jQuery to attach the click event:

```
$("#myButton").click(function(evt) {
   evt.preventDefault();
   document.location.href='@Url.Action("AnotherAction","AnotherController")';
});
```

(Des not matter if you have an `<input type="button">` instead of a `<button>`.

This code will navigate to the AnotherAction of AnotherController. So, if this AnotherAction returns a view, the view will be returned to the browser.

Hope it helps.
Greetings.

Comment: i want to call a page. in my page there is a button. on button click when i click , i opens a pop up window. that window i created in cshtml. i am not understand how to open that page on button click without changing the adress

Answer (score 0):

In MVC you redirect to other views by using the build in html helper @Html.ActionLink

```
Html.ActionLink(article.Title, 
"Login",  // <-- ActionMethod
"Item",   // <-- Controller Name
new { id = article.ArticleID }, // <-- Route arguments.
null  // <-- htmlArguments .. which are none
)
```

Lets say you are in \Home\Index and wish to redirect to another view (\Home\Account.cshtml) 
This would be done this way:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Title", "Account", "Home")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { [args] })
<a href="@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { [args] })"
```

Try to find answer by yourself first please. It's the first steps in all razor docs